# thinking in react with different example?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have seen the thinking in react article found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) and in short it discusses how to break down components...

while i understand the concept in their example and it looks like this..

[image]

each colored box must be a separate component...

now I am creating a login page and i am a bit confused on how to break it down as most of it will not be reused somewhere else and i started to mix multiple concepts together I am wondering if you guys can help me sort my thoughts about this topic

screen shot of similar login page to the one i am making i have already colored components that should be separated based on the react official page docs so please let me know if I am thinking correctly and if any extra tips would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Opinion questions aren't good for Stackoverflow. I'd personally start with putting everything in one component, and then as you build more pages, tabs, etc, see what needs to emerge to support code reuse. You might want a generic tab component that wraps the whole thing and gives you the login and signup tabs, with the login form being its own component inside one of the tabs

Comment: my bad, seems a good idea to start with. and it does not seem like a strict ideology to follow throughout the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React basically is component based library which is re-usable in projects.

For Example you can create the file InputComponent.js :

```
import React from 'react'

function InputComponent() {
    const [name , setName] = React.useState('')
    return (
       <input placeholder="Name" onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)} type="text" ></input>
    )
}

export default InputComponent;
```

And use it anywhere as many as you want like this :

```
import React from 'react'

function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <InputComponent></InputComponent>
            <InputComponent></InputComponent>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

The more re-useable components you can define your project will be more readable and easy foremost .

You can make a re-usable component from anything you desire like some text , input elements and etc ...

You can use component props to pass in any information to the re-usable component to display that information .

For more info you can check the react docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) .

Comment: true what you have said but can this approach backfire in regards to performance ?

Comment: @Raffi This doesn't cause performance issues but even if it does , you can use lazy loading import with react suspense to counter it you can have more info here